# Why can't I find any manpages?

Tags: command-line, manpage, ppc64le

I'm working on a Power8 server running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS:

```
$ uname -a    
Linux power 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:55:30 UTC 2017 ppc64le ppc64le ppc64le GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```

None of the usual manpages appear to be installed. Even a simple command like:

`man man`

returns

```
No manual entry for man
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

This goes for a variety of other tools, like `ls`, `grep`, etc. and library functions like `usleep`, `printf`, and so on.

I've checked that at least some manpages are actually installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i manpages
ii  manpages                           4.04-2                                     all          Manual pages about using a GNU/Linux system
ii  manpages-dev                       4.04-2                                     all          Manual pages about using GNU/Linux for development
ii  manpages-posix                     2013a-1                                    all          Manual pages about using POSIX system
ii  manpages-posix-dev                 2013a-1                                    all          Manual pages about using a POSIX system for development
```

Am I missing something? Is this specific to the `ppc64le` architecture? Or is there something else I can/should install to access these manpages?

**Update:** As requested, I ran `sudo mandb`. The result was:

```
0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
0 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
2 old database entries were purged.
```

<strike>There were no changes to `man man` and other such commands.</strike>

Additionally, the output of `manpath` was:

```
$ manpath -g
/usr/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11R6/man:/opt/man
$ manpath -c
/var/cache/man/oldlocal:/var/cache/man/local:/var/cache/man
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess something is wrong with your manual pages caches, run:

```
sudo mandb
```

to update it, if it does not exist on your system it's going to be created.

You can also use `sudo mandb -c` to fore the removal of old cache and creating a new one.

The other option which may be useful to you is `-t`, it perform correctness checks on manual pages.

If you have some packages installed locally, e.g using `pip` or other package managers in `~/.local/bin` then to add their manual pages once again run it without `sudo`:

```
mandb
```

---

#### Extra steps

If the above instruction did not worked for you use `manpath` to find out about manual search path, make sure it's not empty.

Then check to see if any manual has been installed at all:

```
$ man -w man
/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
```

If the command does not have any result use:

```
$ file /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix
```

Then try `man` to open the manual, see if it works at all:

```
man /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
```

If you didn't find out any man page try reinstalling that package.

Comment: None of this advice works on Ubuntu 18.04, including reinstalling the package.  I have to resort to SSHing into another machine that has Debian installed and reading the man page there!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18 (Bionic). Here's what did work:

```
$ sudo apt install man-db manpages-posix manpages-dev manpages-posix-dev
$ sudo mandb
```

Reference: [How to install man pages on Ubuntu Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-install-man-pages-on-ubuntu-linux/)
.

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Ubuntu 20.04, Focal), GROMACS created a variable $MANPATH that took precedence over the one used by manpages. Using `sudo man` works as well, but adding this line in ~/.bashrc made it permanent.

```
unset MANPATH
```

To go a step further, adding this instead makes sure both GROMACS and manpages work alongside.

```
function man() {              
    unset MANPATH             
    /usr/bin/man ${@}         
    . /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
}
```